# My function doesn't returns any results in APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a function, that is present in my 'APPS' schema. When I execute that function in SQL developer, I get a valid result.

```
declare
v varchar2(1000);
begin
    v := hz_utility_v2pub.get_acct_site_purposes(1095);
    dbms_output.put_line (v);
end;
```

When i execute the same function in my APEX SQL Workshop. I do not get any result. My parsing schema in APEX is also 'APPS'. My statement gets processed successfully but without any result.

What is the problem?

Comment: I'd first check that v is not null when it is run in APEX SQL Workshop. It's possible that a difference in environment settings is affecting the function's behaviour, but without any details on what the function does it's difficult to diagnose from afar.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
declare
v varchar2(1000);
begin
    dbms_output.enable;
    v := hz_utility_v2pub.get_acct_site_purposes(1095);
    dbms_output.put_line (v);
end;
```

or just do this, if all you want is to see the return value of the function:

```
select hz_utility_v2pub.get_acct_site_purposes(1095) from dual;
```